# best way to access data in web application

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4

We use SQL server to store a significant amount of data. Not too big but quite a lot.

We use web services to access them. During the usage of the application we notice that grabbing data is a bottleneck which seems to be the problem for clients. It takes up to 15 seconds to start the application.

Is there any more efficient way to access SQL database than web services or is there a way to cache data while grabbing it?

Comment: Time spent depends on many factors not only the database access. Some of the things to consider is how your SQL is coded and how much data is sent back to the client as well as how many trips your code makes between the client and the server. Your problem as you describe it does not look like a caching issue. However, for caching see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343899/how-to-cache-data-in-a-mvc-application

Comment: You should profile your app to locate the bottleneck. You should figure out if your SQL queries are slow or if its the amount of data that your app is loading.