# Mock Lambda Parameterless Expression

Tags: c#, moq

Getting my head all banged up trying to moq the interface below. The GetOrSet has me tripped up. The service comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343899/how-to-cache-data-in-a-mvc-application)

```
public interface ICacheService
{
    T GetOrSet<T>(string cackeKey, int expiryInMinutes, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class;
}

public class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    public T GetOrSet<T>(string cacheKey, int expiryInMinutes, Func<T> getItemCallback) where T : class
    {

        T item = MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as T;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, item, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expiryInMinutes));
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

Example in code:

```
var result = _cacheService.GetOrSet(
        cacheKey,
        cacheExpiry,
      () => this.GetRoutes(routeType));
return result.Select(x => new Route(x));
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Question is how to moq that GetOrSet<T> method.

Comment: To do what? You can easily set it up with eg `mock.Setup(m => m.GetOrSet("key", 1, () => new TestClass()));`

Answer (score 1):

Basic setup could look like:

```
public static ICacheService GetMockCacheService<T>() where T : class
{
     var mock = new Mock<ICacheService>();

     mock.Setup(service => service.GetOrSet(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<Func<T>>()))
         .Returns(default(T));

     return mock.Object;
}
```

Use a generic method to build your mock for whatever type you need in the implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Seeing your example really helped.